# What does XMLHttpRequest status code -1 mean?

Tags: ajax, internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I've added logging of failed AJAX requests to my application and I'm seeing a lot of failures with a status code of `-1`.

I can't find a definition of the -1 status code anywhere.

Does anyone know what this represents?

I'm seeing it from IE 8.0, Firefox 13, Chrome 20, and more. It doesn't appear to be a browser specific quirk.

Comment: did you trace out the origin for this status code -1? What does that mean? Do we have any fix for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After enhancing our logging to include the status text it was clear what the `-1` code means. `transaction aborted` is what status text shows in Chrome 20.